# excel vba close a workbook opend on other computer

Tags: sharepoint, excel, vba

In excel vba, I want to check if a workbook stored on a SharePoint server is opened by anyone and if it is opened I want to close it, to be able to open it locally and write something in it.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Directions to search for answer, sorry for no direct help as I'm not an VBA expert.

You can detect if a document (including Excel workbook) is checked out in SharePoint document library. You can discard the checkout if you have enough permissions, but you'll not be able to "close workbook" on remote computers where it may be opened. Note that it may be opened without being checked out and checked out without being opened at that particular moment. You should be able to do checkout detection using SharePoint web services.

Opening a workbook locally and saving should be relatively easy by using http://... location on shraepoint, or even \server location if it is enabled on your SharePoint server.

Comment: Thanks. I think I better use a timer to close opened workbook (I have one user that forget to close it and keep it open for half a day...)
To open it from sharepoint locally it's easy...